# QML XmlListModel data sorting

Tags: sorting, qml

how can I sort parsed xml data at QML XmlListModel and then display it in listview.

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way one can. Apparently XmlListModel (in the current Qt Quick 1.0) doesn't support any ordering in its API. XPath if I recall correctly doesn't support any ordering unless you use it with XSLT. It might be a solution if QML had something like [QSortFilerProxyModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) taking XmlListModel as a source. But you can implement it, although you will have to deal with non public Qt API.